# Show that monotone sequence is reducing and bounded by zero?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n=\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^n {1\over{k}} - \log n$ for $n\ge1$. **Euler's Constant** is defined as $y=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$. Show that $(a_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ is decreasing and bounded by zero, and so this limit exists

---

My thought:

When I was trying the first few terms for $a_1, a_2, a_3$, I get:

$$a_1 = 1-0$$

$$a_2={1\over1}+{1\over2}-\log2$$

$$a_3={1\over1}+{1\over2}+{1\over3}-\log3$$

It is NOT decreasing!!! what did I do wrong??

Professor also gave us a hint: Prove that $\dfrac{1}{n+1}\le \log(n+1)-\log n\le \dfrac1n$

we need to use squeeze theorem???

Comment: typo corrected. Thanks!!

Comment: Certainly it's decreasing.  I get $1-0=1$, and $1 + \frac12 -\log2=0.8068528\ldots$, and $1+\frac12+\frac13-\log3=0.73472\ldots$.

Comment: If you didn't get a decreasing sequence of numbers for these first three, I wonder if maybe you pressed the "log" key rather than the "ln" key on a calculator?

Comment: This problem can be solved without calculus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly it's decreasing.  I get $1-0=1$, and $1 + \frac12 -\log2=0.8068528\ldots$, and $1+\frac12+\frac13-\log3=0.73472\ldots$.

$$
\frac{1}{n+1} = \int_n^{n+1}\frac{dx}{n+1} \le \int_n^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x} = \log(n+1)-\log n. 
$$
$$
\frac1n = \int_n^{n+1} \frac{dx}{n} \ge \int_n^{n+1} \frac{dx}{x} = \log(n+1)-\log n.
$$

So
$$
\Big(1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n-\log n\Big) +\Big(\log n\Big) + \Big(\frac{1}{n+1}-\log(n+1)\Big)
$$
$$
\le1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n-\log n.
$$

Comment: oppssss, then bounded by zero can also be explained. But how do I show limit exists???

Comment: If a sequence is monotone (either increasing or decreasing) and bounded, then it converges.

Answer (score 3):

An elementary way to see the inequality is to recall the formal definition of $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\ldots$, so using $\log(n+1)-\log(n)=\log(1+1/n)$ and $1+1/n\leq e^{1/n}$ gives the result upon taking logarithms. The lower bound follows similarly.

Using the inequality your professor gave, look at $a_{n+1}-a_n$ and you'll see the sum term becomes very simple.

Comment: could you explain how the lower bound "similarly" follows?